# Bootstrap datepicker next and previous day buttons

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/) and I want to make 2 buttons(next and previous) that will make the calendar picker go to the next free or the previous free day from the current selected day using jQuery.

It should work with the default event handler that will tell me the selected day.

All i have is this:

```
// Build dayoff dates
var $dayOffDates = [],
    $dayOffFormattedDates = [];
$.each(data.dayoff_dates, function (i, e) {
    $dayOffDates.push(new Date(e));
    $dayOffFormattedDates.push(new Date(e).format('yyyy-mm-dd'));
});

// Check if current date is day off
var $isDayOff = $.inArray(new Date().format('yyyy-mm-dd'), $dayOffFormattedDates);

// Initialize date picker
var $firstCalendarPicker.datepicker({
    language: 'de',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '0d',
    endDate: '+<?php echo ($this->_options->weeks_advance) ? $this->_options->weeks_advance : '3'; ?>w', // backend value
    maxViewMode: 0,
    todayBtn: ($isDayOff === -1) ? 'linked' : false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    toggleActive: true,
    datesDisabled: $dayOffDates
}); 
$('.next').click(function(){
    /*
     * @todo should navigate to the next free date
     */
});
$('.previous').click(function(){
     /*
      * @todo should navigate to the previous free date
      */
});
$firstCalendarPicker.on('changeDate', function (e) {
     if (typeof e != 'undefined' && typeof e.date != 'undefined') {
         //e.date
     }
});
```

Also the next or previous button should be disabled if there are no free past days or future days available.

P.S:
This script also uses the [date format plugin](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) to ease some functions like checking if the current day is off.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Navigate to next date
$('.next').click(function(){
    var $endDate =  new Date($timePickerTableWrap.data('branch-end-date')),
    $selectedDay = $firstCalendarPicker.datepicker('getDate');

    var $tmpSelectedDay= new Date($selectedDay);
    $tmpSelectedDay.setDate($tmpSelectedDay.getDate() + 1);

    // Limit navigation
    if($tmpSelectedDay.getTime() / 1000 < $endDate.getTime() / 1000)
    {
        $firstCalendarPicker.datepicker('update',$tmpSelectedDay);
    }
});

// Navigate to previous date
$('.previous').click(function(){
    var $startDate = new Date($timePickerTableWrap.data('branch-start-date')),
    $selectedDay = $firstCalendarPicker.datepicker('getDate');

    var $tmpSelectedDay = new Date($selectedDay);
    $tmpSelectedDay.setDate($tmpSelectedDay.getDate() -1);

    // Limit navigation
    if($tmpSelectedDay.getTime() / 1000 >= $startDate.getTime() / 1000)
    {
        $firstCalendarPicker.datepicker('update',$tmpSelectedDay);
    } 
});
```

After working some time this provides only navigation to the next or previous date.

Note there are 2 range limits by **$startDate** and **$endDate**.